# vuejs v-for loop is not display anything and i am not getting any errors in my console

Tags: vue.js

My vuejs for loop product is not rendering and no errors are being displayed, when i use a computed property getter, i get this error in my console "Property or method "allProducts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive"

this is my product.js from vuex to manage state

```
       const state = {
        products:[]
        };

      const getters = {
        allProducts: state => state.products
      };

       const mutations = {
         SET_PRODUCT(state,products) {
         state.products = products
       }

       const actions = {
         async fetchProducts({commit}) {

          let response = await Api().get('/products/loadproducts');          
          commit('SET_PRODUCT',response.data.products)
       }
     }
```

this is a snippet from my ProductComponent

```
   computed:{
    ...mapGetters['allProducts']
   },
   methods:{
    ...mapActions(['fetchProducts']),
    ...mapMutations(['SET_PRODUCT']),
   },

   created(){
     this.fetchProducts();
   }
```

this is the code from my template to loop through products,

```
        <div class="py-5">
            list of products

             <ul v-for="product in fetchProducts()" :key="product.id">
                    <li>{{product}}</li>
             </ul>    
        </div>
```

this is an image from my console which show all the product have been retrieve by nothing is displaying in the for loop
[image]

Comment: `v-for="product in allProducts"` doesn't work?....have you reviewed the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)

Comment: Is `...mapGetters['allProducts']` how you have it in your real code or just a typo in the question? It's missing the parentheses. `...mapGetters(['allProducts'])`

Comment: thanks @skirtle, i don't know i missed it